# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - February 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the fifth edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for February 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      430
2   grgarside                  180
3   JMY1000                    170
4   pjc90                      150
5   bmike, patrix, Monomeeth,
    Mark                        90
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

A total of 1,461 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-02-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   klanomath                 61
2   Allan                     57
3   grgarside                 31
4   IconDaemon                30
5   bmike                     23
```

A big thank you to all 16 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,492
2   Monomeeth                 564
3   Melvin Jefferson          230
4   FTP                       191
5   LangLangC                 190
```

A big thank you to all 47 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted at least 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     74
2   Mark, JMY1000             71
3   pjc90                     46
4   patrix                    45
5   fsb                       35
```

A big thank you to all 22 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    162
2   JMY1000, pjc90           101
3   patrix                    71
4   Scot                      64
5   ProGrammer                55
```

A big thank you to all 40 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     96
2   LangLangC                 39
3   pjc90                     31
4   JMY1000                   27
5   Scot                      20
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     69
2   JMY1000                   30
3   Mark                      26
4   Tetsujin                  19
5   pjc90                     18
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    25
2   patrix                   15
3   JMY1000                  12
4   Mark, IconDaemon          9  
5   pjc90, Tetsujin, fsb      8
```

A big thank you to all 18 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    58
2   Monomeeth                23
3   pjc90                    22
4   Scot, grgarside          21
5   Glorfindel               16
```

A big thank you to all 42 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1st. [Are there ways to have Mac OS recognize my password “better”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314569/are-there-ways-to-have-mac-os-recognize-my-password-better)

- Posted by: GhostCat
- Votes: **31**

2nd. [How to screenshot Netflix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316096/how-to-screenshot-netflix)

- Posted by: theonlygusti
- Votes: **11**

Equal 3rd. [USB-C to MagSafe 2 Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316400/usb-c-to-magsafe-2-adapter)

- Posted by: LinusGeffarth
- Votes: **7**

Equal 3rd. [Is there a menu bar tool which will let me eject external drives easily?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315134/is-there-a-menu-bar-tool-which-will-let-me-eject-external-drives-easily)

- Posted by: Skeleton Bow
- Votes: **7**

Equal 3rd. [What does 'Terminal' derive from?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314751/what-does-terminal-derive-from)

- Posted by: Yumi Tada
- Votes: **7**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [Are there ways to have Mac OS recognize my password “better”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314569/are-there-ways-to-have-mac-os-recognize-my-password-better/314578#314578)

   - Answered by: CajunLuke
   - Votes: **32**
2. [How to screenshot Netflix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316096/how-to-screenshot-netflix/316097#316097)

   - Answered by: IconDaemon
   - Votes: **21**
3. [What does 'Terminal' derive from?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314751/what-does-terminal-derive-from/314752#314752)

   - Answered by: grgarside
   - Votes: **16**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Are there ways to have Mac OS recognize my password “better”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314569/are-there-ways-to-have-mac-os-recognize-my-password-better)

   - Posted by: GhostCat
   - Views: **4,915**
2. [How to screenshot Netflix?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316096/how-to-screenshot-netflix)

   - Posted by: theonlygusti
   - Views: **3,082**
3. [What does 'Terminal' derive from?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314751/what-does-terminal-derive-from)

   - Posted by: Yumi Tada
   - Views: **2,455**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [GhostCat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/257137/ghostcat)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [CajunLuke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1629/cajunluke)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [GhostCat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/257137/ghostcat)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In February our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 387 flags with an average handling time of 16 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 90 comments
- deleted 214 posts
- closed 171 posts
- edited 102 posts
- created 70 posts
- created 232 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)